# TanStack useInfiniteQuery caching fetchNextPage to fetch the first page

Tags: reactjs, tanstackreact-query, tanstack

```
  const fetchProjects = async ({ pageParam = 0 }) => {
    const res = await fetch('/api/projects?cursor=' + pageParam)
    return res.json()
  }

  const {
    data,
    error,
    fetchNextPage,
    hasNextPage,
    isFetching,
    isFetchingNextPage,
    status,
  } = useInfiniteQuery({
    queryKey: ['projects'],
    queryFn: fetchProjects,
  })
```

This is a sample code. On the first render it is fetching the first page as required. That data then put into the table that has scroll in it. And in simple case we would call `fetchNextPage` when user scrolled to bottom.

In my case, the height of a table is big enough to contain all the data from first page, and even though callback to `fetchNextPage` is called (calculated based on height of the table and scroll to end), it does not fetch the second page.

I've checked for `isFetching` flag - it is set to false (i.e. no simultanious fetches). Even more, there are no fetch data in the network displayed.

is it something to do with `page` caching that is handles by react-tanstack?

Checked for every flag that is available (i.e. returned from `useInfiniteQuery`), logically everything should work fine but it doesnt.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the prop `getNextPageParam`.

Without it, `useInfiniteQuery` has no way of getting the "next" page as it does not know what would be "next".

See [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-star-g3zllp?file=/src/App.js) where the `getNextPageParam` is commented out and uncomment it to see the difference.

Comment: getNextPageParam should not be specified if pagination is fully controlled by `useInfiniteQuery` itself. 

In the example you showed in the sandbox, if i wanted to load page #1 (i.e. change `const nextPage = pages.length + 1`), it would give error in the console that id 1 is already in the store

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to say. And it is hard to debug your code without a reproducible example. In the code you are providing, you are missing the callback `getNextPageParam`. I have showed you with a basic example that this will cause the behavior you are seeing. If you tried my answer and it did not help, please post updated code. Otherwise, try it.

Comment: Also, please clarify "pagination is fully controlled by useInfiniteQuery". How do you expect `pageParam = 0` to ever be anything but `0`? You aren't setting it anywhere and `useInfiniteQuery` is not going to guess what you want it to be on the next page.